# People in India

Tags: prepositions

Is the following sentence grammatical? Can I use **in** twice in the following sentence?

> People **in** India work as labourers **in** many western countries.

Answer (score 4):

> People **from** India work as labourers in many western countries.

since a person can't be in India and in a western country simultaneously. *From* shows the country of origin (= India), whereas *in* hints at their current location (= a western country).

Comment: Can I say the following sentences : 1- Students at/from this school are playing at the ground.  2- Many people in/from the Us work in New York.

Comment: "Students at/from this school are playing at the ground" might just be acceptable in very specific circumstances but generally, neither "at" nor "from" could work and they are clearly not interchangeable.

"Many people in the US work in New York" is fine.

"Many people from the US work in New York" might not be grammatically wrong but it won't work semantically or syntactically.

"… from all over/various parts of the US…" is fine.

"… people from the US…" by itself suggests they are no longer in the US, so can't be working in New York.